# Função Javascript que recebe dois números (input) e exibe em uma lista (alert) com todos os números pares entre eles

Tags: javascript

Olá, Pessoal!

Podem me ajudar com o código abaixo?

Gostaria que ele retornasse uma lista com todos os números pares que entrarem nos inputs.

```
document.querySelector("#btnNumPar").addEventListener("click", function() {
    const inputNumUm = document.querySelector("#inputNumPar").value.trim();
    const inputDoisNum = document.querySelector("#inputNumParDois").value.trim();
    let todosPares=[];
    for (let i = 0; i <= inputDoisNum; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            todosPares.push();
            console.log(todosPares)
            // alert(`Os números pares entre ${inputNumUm} e ${inputDoisNum} são: ${todosPares}`);

        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Você precisa dizer ao método push o que quer inserir na array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que o primeiro numero sempre será maior que o segundo, e que você deseja os numeros pares dentro do intervalo de valores recebidos dos inputs, você deve deixar seu loop da seguinte forma:

```
for (let i = parseInt(inputNumUm); i <= parseInt(inputDoisNum); i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            todosPares.push(i);
        }
    }
```

Após isso basta realizar o alert:

```
alert(`Os números pares entre ${inputNumUm} e ${inputDoisNum} são: ${todosPares}`);
```

Comment: Gabriel, muito obrigada!
Só mais uma dúvida.
O alert está retornando um por um os itens do array, como eu poderia retornar todos os itens de uma só vez?

Comment: Você precisa deixar seu alert fora do `for`, caso contrário sempre que o número for par ele irá executar seu `alert`

Comment: Obrigada novamente, Gabriel!